# Visual Studio 2015 IntelliSense QuickTip missing

Tags: visual-studio-2015

How can I enable the tooltips when I select a class or head over with the mouse? I tried to repair (which takes 1 hour), reset all settings to default, but nothing solved the problem. I think I used a wrong keyboard shortcuts and now it is gone. This is how it looks now, but I want the full information.

[image: Visual Studio IntelliSense tooltipp]

EDIT:
Just to make it clear, I want the information what the methods,... are doing. Like in Java:

[image]

As beginner to C# it is really helpful.

EDIT2:

Here you can see how the VS is showing some information about the class. It is in German, but I think as example it should work.
[image]

Comment: I don't think Visual Studio has the same thing.  At least not the way you're used to it in Eclipse (or whatever Java IDE you're using).

Comment: Yes it is from eclipse. I use VS in the work too and there I get this popups too. I can make a screenshot on monday to show you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is a missing part in the language packs. I have installed the VS in German and changed the language to Englisch. But the downloaded language pack from Microsoft is not complete. After I changed it back to German the info box shows up.

EDIT:
Repair installation or `devenv.exe /resetuserdata` didn't solved the problem.